Redhat not booting, unsupported hardware device message appear
I have a redhat workstation, it's not booting and showing the error below:
UNSUPPORTED HARDWARE DEVICE: Haswell HDMI Audio
[drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0x9E49: Init table command not found: 0xA9
Can anyone help me with that, I'm not a linux expert and I appreciate any help
Thanks

To help get an answer can you edit and include (a) Which version of Redhat is is in use (b) the identify of the presumably NVIDIA graphics card (b) If you can boot to a shell the output of lspci -nn -v -s 0000:01:00.0 to display information about the PCI device the nouveau driver is reporting the Init table command not found: 0xA9 message about.
